# Android ListView in fragment - problem with table refreshing after getting new data

Tags: android, listview, retrofit, retrofit2

As I mentioned in my topic, I've a problem with updating my data downloaded from API directly to ListView, so there is simple explaintation:

Ive created the fragment with search view and list view.
Now using the onCreateView() im loading first array data for my table.

```
public ArrayList<item_list> myListView;
```

Then im trying to implement the searcher with code like this:

```
      searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.searchBar);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    myListView.clear();
                CallMyFunction(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

In the CallMyFunction I've an identical function like in the initial function to build a first adapter with data for my ListView.

Ok now when im using this function im getting 200, also im getting new values but they just aren't adding to my ListView.

My function:

```
   public void CallMyFunction(String searchString){
        String token = this.token;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Loading the ListView...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        listOfData = new ArrayList<>();


        Call<List<ItemDataClass>> itemDataClassCall = ApiLoginInterface.ITEM_DATA_CLASS_CALL(searchString,token);

        itemDataClassCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<ItemDataClass>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ItemDataClass>> call, Response<List<ItemDataClass>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<ItemDataClass> itemsResponse = response.body();

                    for(ItemDataClass getList : itemsResponse) {

                        response_item_list itemList = new response_item_list();
                        itemList.setDescription(getList.getDESCRIPTION());

                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        imageBytes = Base64.decode(getList.getIMAGE(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);

                        itemList.set_image(decodedImage);
                        itemList.set_name(getList.getPRODUCER());
                       itemList.set_content(getList.getCONTENT());
                        itemList.set_cost(getList.getCost());
                        itemList.set_contest(getList.getCONTEST());
                        itemList.set_content(getList.getRH_CONTENT());
                        itemList.set_weight(getList.getWEIGHT());
                        itemList.set_index(getList.getINDEX());
                       myListView.add(itemList);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, ""+ response.code());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CatalystDataClass>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

and with those code the weird is that im getting an empty view after calling searching something (so after calling this function too) or im getting old table values..

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your `myListView` is just a `List` not a `ListView`, then it is normal that nothing is displayed. You need to create a `ListView` in your xml, and link it to your items with an adapter that will display it.

Comment: Hi, I did it - myListView is just a list of items to my ListView :P

Comment: I don't have a problem with loading data, initial load working fine, but when im typing something in my searcher then problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i resolved my problem.

To change data you just need to refresh the adapter, but it's not that easy as I think, there is more than `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. You need to create a simple function in an adapter:

```
    public void clearlistview() {
       items.clear();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

then after clearing the list you have to call the adapter one more time, to prepare a new list view:

```
 adapter = new item_Adapter(getActivity(),listOfItems);
                listView = view.findViewById(R.id.items_tableView);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

that's resolved my problem.